# How can I use fails method validation in controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

controller validator in laravel :

```
$validationController = $this->validate(request(), [
      'title' => 'min:100',
      'text' => 'required',
      'image' => 'required',
]);
```

and we can make validator with :

```
$validationNormaly = Validator::make(request(), [
      'title' => 'min:100',
      'text' => 'required',
      'image' => 'required',
]);
```

and i can't use $validationController->fails(). how can i use it?

Answer (score 1):

The first validation that you mentioned will fail automatically as designed by the laravel code base.

The `Validator::make()` i typically use when doing ajax requests and such to the controller method. You will need to run the validation fails method to invoke the failed response like so:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('post/create')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    }
```

Comment: I recommend using `Validator::validate` to prevent that unneeded `if`.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use :

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ])->validate();
```

take advantage of the automatic redirection with error messages